# Runnable with a time limit

Tags: java, multithreading

Trying to construct a `Runnable` that **must** end within a given time limit.

Currently I'm using `java.util.Timer` to interrupt `Runnable` thread.

`Timer` starts right after `Runnable` starts.

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class test {
    Thread task;
    Timer  timer;

    public void start(){

        task = new Thread(new worker());
        timer = new Timer("timer",true);

        task.start();
        timer.schedule(new Terminator(),1000*2);
    }


    class worker implements Runnable{
        @Override
        public void run() {

            for (int i = 0 ; i < 2; i++){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("Test Interrupted !!");
                    return;
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Test Finished !!");
            timer.cancel();
        }
    }

    class Terminator extends TimerTask{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            task.interrupt();
            System.out.println("Test Terminated !!");
        }
    }
}
```

But I suspect this results in a race condition between `Timer` and `Runnable` threads:
`Runnable` is about to complete, and `Timer` is also firing.

Can this ever result in both *Finished !!* and *Terminated !!* being printed ? If so, how one avoids it ?

Update:

It happens:

```
11-09 21:14:40.741: INFO/System.out(31442): Test Finished !! 18
11-09 21:14:40.751: INFO/System.out(31442): Test Terminated !! 18
11-09 21:14:40.751: INFO/System.out(31442): Test Finished !! 19
11-09 21:14:40.751: INFO/System.out(31442): Test Terminated !! 19
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but have a look at [`TimeLimiter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/TimeLimiter.html) from [tag:guava]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can this ever result in both Finished !! and Terminated !! being printed ?

Yes. When the message "finished" is printed it's possible that the timer will fire before it is cancelled.

```
System.out.println("Finished !!");
// The timer can fire here.
timer.cancel();
```

If this happens, both messages will be printed.

---

To avoid the problem you can use synchronization.

```
synchronized (someObject) {
    if (!finished) {
        finished = true;
        System.out.println("Finished !!");
        timer.cancel(); 
    }
}
```

And in the terminator:

```
synchronized (someObject) {
    if (!finished) {
        finished = true;
        task.interrupt();
        System.out.println("Test Terminated !!");
    }
}
```

This prevents both messages form being printed.

Comment: Note that `finished` must be `volatile`.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up with with a simple `if(ended.compareAndSet(false,true))` check on an `AtomicBoolean` called `ended`, in place of synchronize blocks.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. If you want to avoid that, you need use `synchronize` and a shared lock objects:

```
public class test {
    private Object lock = new Object();
    ...

        synchronized(lock) {
            System.out.println("Test Finished !!");
            timer.cancel();
        }
    ...

        synchronized(lock) {
            if( ! task.isRunning() ) return;

            task.interrupt();
            System.out.println("Test Terminated !!");
        }

    ...
```

Comment: this is sort of nitpicking, but there is still a time between entering the `synchronized()` block and the *actual task finishing* (in this case, 2 `Thread.sleep()`s) - your solution only really prevents the two lines from being printed at the same time regardless of state of the task. am i thinking too far into this? is there a better solution?

Comment: There is no way to prevent the race between "work is finished" and "kill timer" since Java has no way to say "create lock when this block of code is finished". The goal is to write code which always behaves. It doesn't matter when the timer cancels the "kill timer" code. But it might be a problem when the timer is canceled twice or something like that.

Comment: then why bother with synchronizing on an object? if we are only able to disguise the race condition as proper synchronization, is it more appropriate to have an outside object/thread monitor the state of the task? the task could store a boolean to determine whether or not it was interrupted, and the outside thread could wait for the task to finish and then print the correct line according to the boolean. i am not satisfied with your response! there must be a proper way :) edit: you edited your comment to add the "always behaves" part, and that makes sense. i suppose there is nothing to "fix".